# Get the app engine ip address for websocket

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, websocket, gcloud

I deployed my app to gcloud using app engine service but now I don't know how to get my app ip to use websocket on the client project. I followed the official example on gcloud github repo to deploy. Thank you.

Comment: can you please post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found a workaround for this, I add a function to get the app's public external IP and then console log it out, find the logs and use it for the our web app.
If anyone has a better solution, please let me know! Thank you.